# VB.NET: Class is not being called

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I have something like this:

```
    Public Class Test

      Public Sub myCalculation()

        Debug.Print("I'm here!!!")
        'A LOT of code

      End sub

      Public Shared Sub Main()
        Debug.Print("calling calculations...")
        Test.myCalculation()
      End Sub
   End Class
```

The Problem is: `Sub Main()` is running OK, I see `"calling calculations..."` in Immediate Window but I don't see `"I'm here!!!"` text. It looks like `myCalculations()` is not being called. Is that something wrong with this code?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Add `Shared` to myCalculation or create an instance of it. But currently it shouldn't compile at all.

Comment: myCalculation does not appear to be a static method.  Try simply calling `myCalculation()`, rather than `Test.myCalculation()`.

Comment: @RobertHarvey "Cannot refer ro an instance member of class from within a shared method or shared member initializer without an explicit instance of the class"

Comment: @Downvoter may I know why?

Comment: Not the downvoter, but don't ignore @TimSchmelter's comment.  Your posted code doesn't compile.

Comment: @LarsTech Error count is zero... I've no idea what's going on :(

Comment: Start a new project and copy this code.  You should get a `Reference to a non-shared member requires an object reference` pointing to the line `Test.myCalculation()`

Comment: @I still don't know the reason of the Downvote :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot see "I'm here!!!" because your code did not compile.  The default settings in Visual Studio make this a bit too likely for you not to notice this.  It does display a message box to warn you about it but it is easy to ignore and even easier to never see it again when you click the "Don't show again" option in the box.

Use Tools + Options, Projects and Solutions, Build and Run.  Change the "On Run, when projects are out of date" setting to "Always build".  Just below that, change "On Run, when build or deployment error occurs" to "Do not launch".

You can now never again accidentally run an old version of your program.

And fix the bug, myCalculation() must be `Shared` to be called like that.